# Issues with if / ifelse

Tags: r

I have a data set with a field containing unstructured date information. I'm trying to convert it to date, however the field has 2 forms of date, one with am / pm and one 24 hr clock.

If I try and convert it straight off, it breaks and obviously gives incorrect answers.

As such after doing some checking I started with a simple if function. The main distinguisher between a field with the am/pm is the length of the field so I tried the following:

```
dateCheck <- function(x) {
if(nchar(x) > 17) {
strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
} else {
strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
}
}
```

This wasnt working and was returning the following error:

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

After some research I saw that there are some issues with using if functions, and I should probably use ifelse and came up with the following:

```
ifelse(nchar(x) > 17,strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"),strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))
```

This really messes with my data frame and gives me an absolute garbage readout.
It also recently started giving me the following error:

> Warning messages: 1: In ifelse(nchar(fb2$Date) > 17,
>   strptime(fb2$Date, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"),  :   number of items to
>   replace is not a multiple of replacement length 2: In
>   ifelse(nchar(fb2$Date) > 17, strptime(fb2$Date, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"), 
>   :   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Any idea what I should do?

Edit: With Sample Data

```
The type with the AM / PM
04/20/2015 3:47 pm
04/20/2015 3:32 pm
04/19/2015 12:45 pm
04/18/2015 9:00 pm
04/16/2015 2:52 pm
04/14/2015 4:40 pm
04/14/2015 10:48 am
04/14/2015 10:28 am

The type without
04/11/2015 11:28
04/10/2015 16:12
04/09/2015 16:44
04/08/2015 12:12
04/08/2015 11:38
04/07/2015 12:11
04/05/2015 08:45
```

Which means that an example of the data together would look like

```
04/16/2015 2:52 pm
04/14/2015 4:40 pm
04/14/2015 10:48 am
04/14/2015 10:28 am
04/11/2015 11:28
04/10/2015 16:12
04/09/2015 16:44
04/03/2015 08:57
04/02/2015 17:41
04/01/2015 11:44
03/28/2015 12:45 pm
03/28/2015 10:59 am
03/27/2015 4:13 pm
03/23/2015 5:02 pm
03/22/2015 4:06 pm
03/22/2015 1:10 pm
03/21/2015 8:20 am
03/19/2015 10:12 am
03/18/2015 1:41 pm
03/17/2015 1:41 pm
03/13/2015 4:03 pm
03/12/2015 15:19
03/12/2015 11:05
03/11/2015 16:12
03/11/2015 09:46
03/08/2015 19:29
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Also, in your `ifelse` statement, the first `strptime` has `/%d#` and the second has `/%d`. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: `sapply(original_vector, dateCheck)` should work but the `ifelse` should have as well. As John said, we need data.

Comment: sample data would be: "04/14/2015 10:28 am" for one type and "04/11/2015  11:28:00" for another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
raw.vector <- c("04/16/2015 2:52 pm", "04/14/2015 4:40 pm", "04/14/2015 10:48 am"
                     , "04/11/2015 11:28", "04/10/2015 16:12")

mod.vector <- strptime(raw.vector,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
ind <- is.na(mod.vector)
mod.vector[ind] <- strptime(raw.vector[ind],"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

It should Works without warning.
But don't know what product the warning.

Comment: Thanks so much!! That worked perfectly. Cheers for the help - shoulda thought about that work around, but still wondering why my ifelse didn't work. Would upvote if I could but not enough rep!